# Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: video/mp4"

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have video in server url then i'm downloading from url using AFNetworking for later playing the video. But while downloading i got below error

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: video/mp4" UserInfo=0x1e8b6d30 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://center.net/projects/AR/Medica/focusvideo.mp4, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x1d55c260>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: video/mp4}
```

code for download the video:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
 NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"images"];

 if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

 [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

 [manager setResponseSerializer:[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]];
 manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"video/mpeg", nil];



 [manager GET:@"http://center.net/projects/AR/Medica/focusvideo.mp4"
 parameters:nil
 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
 [operation.responseData writeToFile:[dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"focusvideo.mp4"] atomically:YES];


 NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataPath]);
 NSLog(@"THE RESPONSE: %@", responseObject);


 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error1) {
 NSLog(@"%@", error1);
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

In AFURLResponseSerialization.m file Just add `video/mpeg` 
 in acceptable contact type.

Instead of :

```
self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
```

Use this :

```
self.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html",@"video/mpeg", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If using AFNetworking 2.0, you can use the `POST` method, which simplifies this a bit:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username":username, @"password":password};
[manager POST:@"https://mycompany.atlassian.net/rest/auth/latest/session/" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

This does the creation of the request, setting its `Content-Type` according to the `requestSerializer` setting, and encodes the JSON for you. One of the advantages of AFNetworking is that you can get out of the weeds of constructing and configuring `NSURLRequest` objects manually.